# Using reg.exe in code with limited privileges

Tags: c#, permissions, registry

I need to get installed software list under restricted user.

I use this code:

```
string fullString = string.Format("EXPORT \"{0}\\{1}\" \"{2}\" /y", hiveString, keyPath, Path.GetTempFileName());
Log(fullString);
var p = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("reg.exe", fullString) {RedirectStandardOutput = true, UseShellExecute = false,WorkingDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()});
Log("Output: " + p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
p.WaitForExit();
```

On my dev machine I see normal output:

> *operation completed successfully*

No matter what account I use - admin or restricted user.

Then I ran this app on Windows XP under restricted user. And see next in log:

> "Output: "

Empty line, yes.

When I run similiar query in cmd - it works fine. I can not understand, what I'm doing wrong.

Why doesn't `reg.exe` write anything?

Answer (score 1):

You **can't** call reg.exe without admin privileges. At least not unless you are on Windows Millennium (that's why it doesn't even appear on MSFT Web Site). Imagine what one could do if it were possible...

Comment: *You can't call reg.exe without admin privileges* Could you give any reference? I think access to registry keys is based on permissions needed by specific keys. See [How to set or change registry editing permissions in Windows XP or in Windows Server 2003](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310426)